# android: navigation drawer click issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on an app which has drawer layout with fragments.
There is a textview too which says signout in the drawer.

The issue is the signout works well initially. But when i switch to different activity and return back to previous activity then on opening the drawer, signout becomes unclickable as in the content below the drawer is getting clicked instead of signout.

The basic code for drawer layout is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private LinearLayout drawer_linear;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;    

public static final String TAG = "FeedTag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawer_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_linear);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do Something            
        }
    });

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), true, String.valueOf(unreadCount)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            //R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawer_linear);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawer_linear);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

    try {
        if(((Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TimeTableFragment")).isVisible() && !drawerOpen) {
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_action_refresh, true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_remind).setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tag = "";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            tag = "Fragment1";
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            tag = "Fragment2";
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            tag = "Fragment3";
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            tag = "Fragment4";
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Fragment5();
            tag = "Fragment5";
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Fragment6();
            tag = "Fragment6";
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new Fragment7();
            tag = "Fragment7";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
        transaction.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer_linear);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

The xml is

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_linear"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/userEmail"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/userEmail"
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
                android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example where it's possible to reproduce the problem, otherwise we can't help you. Also are there any log outputs?